# App hanging randomly on __psynch_mutexwait ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, dylib

I'm using Parse.com as my backend, but since a few times, my app freezes randomly... (but don't crashes...) I'm setting "pause" with the debugger at the freeze time and I'm getting this on the right-left window:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone could explain me why that is happening exactly ? I precise that I'm not using too much background tasks...

Comment: Need to see your code to see what is happening.

Comment: I'm using NSTimer to loop data, I have precisely 2 timers one that is looping new users'states ('online', 'offline' 'busy' etc...) and another timer that is getting the news about users to have real-time updates (the timers are invalidated correctly and nothing is wrong at that point) do you think that is because of loops ?

Comment: show code of your solution

Comment: The problem is that I don't even know where it is happening, it happens between two viewcontrollers and link both codes could be long... :/ firstly I just want to know what does "__psynch_mutexwait" means generally to figure out what problem is persisting...

I wanted to search and find more informations about it without results...

Comment: well from images above, it is happening on your viewDidLoad function on a Parse object. Can wee see the code in there ?

Comment: The problem is happening in MSMenuViewController's viewDidLoad method right ?

Comment: `psync_mutexwait` is a function used to wait for a lock.  The thread is blocked until the lock is available.  You need to figure out what `[PFObject objectForKey` might be waiting for, and restructure your code to prevent it getting stuck.  Check other threads to see what they are doing; you haven't provided enough context to help more specifically.